# React native props TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but I have the following component

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements';

const propTypes = {
    selected: PropTypes.bool,
    name: PropTypes.string,
};

const TabIcon = (props) => {
    return <Icon name={props.name} size={28} type={"font-awesome"}  />
};

TabIcon.propTypes = propTypes;

export default TabIcon;
```

And then the following

```
<Scene key='Home' component={Home} title='Home' initial={true} icon={TabIcon({name:'home'})} />
```

I keep getting TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON"

Comment: You might want to add the code for your `Scene` component as well.

Comment: Can you please add code of `Scene` component as well, it seems you have called component in circular format.

Comment: the Scene component is just the react-native-router-flux, it's just the routing and how you setup it up.

Comment: I am having the same problem, and its caused by the Icon of react-native-elements. Did you solved it?